# Are both of these volatile qualifier usages redundant?

Tags: c, syntax, language-lawyer, declaration, volatile

Consider

```
volatile int volatile * volatile vip; // (1)
```

and

```
volatile int volatile * volatile vipa[10]; // (2)
```

Both lines of code trigger `-Wduplicate-decl-specifier` (see [rev 236142](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?limit_changes=0&view=revision&revision=236142)
and [gcc7 release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-7/changes.html)). I'd like to know if I can remove some `volatile` specifiers from the given code without changing the semantics of the code, and understand the reasons behind it, too.

Thus, the following questions:

**a**. In (1), do the 1st and 2nd `volatile` qualifiers both refer to `int`, thus being "duplicate" in gcc terms? (I'm looking at C99 6.7.3.4 here.)

**b**. In (2), does one of the `volatile` qualifiers refer to the type of the array, and not the `int` or the pointer itself, so that C99 6.7.3.8 holds:

> If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so-qualified, not the array type.

or do the `volatile` specifiers in (2) only affect the `int` and the `pointer` type, and not the type of the array?

**c**. If the answer to **b** is negative, how do I declare a `volatile` array type that is described in C99 6.7.3.8? Is it the syntax described at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array (quote follows)?

> qualifiers    -   any combination of const, restrict, or volatile qualifiers, only allowed in function parameter lists; this qualifies the pointer type to which this array parameter is transformed

Let's consider this a question about C99. If there are any differences in C11 in this regard, please make a note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:

> - In (1), do the 1st and 2nd `volatile` qualifiers both refer to `int`, thus being "duplicate" in gcc terms? (I'm looking at C99 6.7.3.4 here.)

yes, they both qualify the `int` and they're *the* duplicate.

> - In (2), does one of the volatile qualifiers refer to the type of the array, and `not` the int or the pointer itself, so that C99 6.7.3.8 holds:

C99 6.7.3.8 does *not* hold here. The qualifier already applies to the element type. It is possible to apply a qualifier to an array with a typedef, but that also qualifies the element type (see below)

> c. If the answer to b is negative, how do I declare a volatile array type that is described in C99 6.7.3.8?

With a `typedef` for example.

---

The C standard explicitly allows qualifiers to occur more than once. [C11 n1570 6.7.3p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p5):

> If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same specifier-qualifier-list, either directly or via one or more typedefs, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

i.e. what `-Wduplicate-decl-specifier` is not an error as such, but such code verbatim *is* suspicious - should it be `volatile int *volatile` that was misspelt as `volatile int volatile *` causing the pointer to be unqualified...

---

The qualifiers apply to type of the left *left* of the qualifier, except if the qualifier itself is the leftmost one, in which case it is as if it was right of the base type i.e.

```
volatile int *
```

and

```
int volatile *
```

mean the same thing. Therefore in `volatile int volatile` you can remove one of these. Thus the thing what you need is

```
volatile int *volatile vipa[10];
```

Meaning that **vipa`is an array of 10`volatile`-qualified pointers to`volatileint`s.**

---

What the C99 6.7.3p8/C11 6.7.3p9 means is that an *array* as itself cannot be volatile - its address is constant, only its elements can be qualified. hence if an array type is qualified, it only applies to its elements. This is even so if a typedef is qualified:

```
typedef int intarray[5];
const intarray myarray;
```

will declare `myarray` as if by

```
const int myarray[5];
```

whereas if you'd use typedef for a pointer:

```
typedef int *intptr;
const intptr myptr;
```

this qualifier would not affect the pointed-to type but be equivalent to

```
int *const myptr;
```

---

While both `volatile int` and `int volatile` are strictly allowed, the C standard prefers the former. [C11 n1570 6.7.6.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1p3):

> 3. **EXAMPLE** The following pair of declarations demonstrates the difference between a ''variable pointer to a constant value'' and a ''constant pointer to a variable value''.
>
>    ```
>    const int *ptr_to_constant;
>    int *const constant_ptr;
>    ```
>
>    The contents of any object pointed to by `ptr_to_constant` shall not be modified through that pointer, but `ptr_to_constant` itself may be changed to point to another object. Similarly, the contents of the `int` pointed to by `constant_ptr` may be modified, but `constant_ptr` itself shall always point to the same location.

---

It is further possible to add a type qualifier for an *array* within the brackets, but only in function parameters, so you can write

```
void foo(int array[volatile])
```

which means *almost the same* and the parameter decays to a qualified pointer

```
void foo(int *volatile array)
```

but you can use the `static` specifier only with the former style.

Comment: Thanks! Just make sure I understand this part correctly. "If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers..." - this is essentially the  last sentence in your answer, correct? Does the "array type specificatoin that includes qualifiers" look like the last declaration in the answer?

Comment: The fact that an array cannot be qualified is not related to the fact that its address is constant. Every object has a constant address. The reason qualifiers apply to elements and not arrays is that an array can never be used as an object in a way where qualifiers would apply.

Answer (score 3):

the explanation is simple.

`volatile int *` == `int volatile *`

in this case order does not matter.

So `volatile int * volatile x;` == `int volatile * volatile x;`

if you have `volatile int volatile *` you have already declared it as volatile do  the second one is not needed